# Codeigniter HMVC and ion_auth with ajaxForm

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, ajaxform

I am developing a site with Codeigniter 2.1.3

I am using HMVC to create ion_auth modules.

I am trying to separate my frontend and backend login system.

I created two modules for ion_auth:
application/modules/auth - for the frontend
application/modules/admin - for the backend

Both have the same files, except the admin auth controller is calling a different login view.

My homepage view calls the login view like this:

```
echo Module::run('auth/login');
```

Both auth controllers extend Frontend_controller which extends MY_Controller.
MY_Controller is in application/core and it extends MX_Controller.

The login view for the frontend is using ajaxForm to submit the form:

```
<div id="login_form">
<?php
 $attr = array('class'=>'form-inline', 'id'=>'loginForm');
 $send = array('class'=>'btn btn-inverse', 'name'=>'signin', 'value'=>'Sign In');
 echo form_open(site_url('auth/login', $attr));
?>
<div >
 <img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/login.gif'); ?>" alt="Login" />
</div>
<div  left; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;padding-top:25px;margin-right:45px">LOGIN</div>

<div left">
 <?php echo form_label('Cellphone', 'cellphone', array('class'=>'login-label')); ?>
</div>
<div class="span2"  padding-top:10px"><?php echo form_input('identity', set_value('identity', ''), 'placeholder="cellphone no" class="span2 phone" id="cellphone"'); ?></div>

<div left; margin-left:10px"><?php echo form_label('Password', 'password', array('class'=>'login-label')); ?></div>
<div class="span2"  padding-top:10px"><?php echo form_password('password', '', 'placeholder="password" class="span2" id="password"'); ?></div>
<div class="span1" ><?php echo form_submit($send); ?></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitLogin" value="1" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(function()
{
 var options = { 
 target: '#login_form',
 success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
 };

 $('#loginForm').ajaxForm(options);

// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
   alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
} 
});
</script>
```

I have a few problems:

Problem One: I read through the HMVC documentation and added these lines to the MY_Controller file:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;
```

I created a MY_Form_validation file in: application/libraries:

```
class My_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation()
{
 public $CI;
}
```

After doing this when I go to my homepage I get this error:
Cannot access protected property CI_Form_validation::$CI in C:\sites\tl\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line 12

Problem two: If I don’t do these form validation changes and try to submit the login form on the homepage it opens the login view again in a new page with no errors. It looks like it is not using jquery to submit the form

Please, can someone help with that?

I am struggling for days now to have this login system working.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the login form does not submit through the jQuery ajaxForm call, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

When I first discovered the HMVC extension I started by using Modules::run(), and then faced problems similar to yours, so I had to figure out an alternative way to do things while making use of both CI native features and HMVC. My conclusion was to make a Frontend_Controller and a Backend_controller which both inherit from Base_controller. The latter has a template rendering layer and other common functionality.

The way I organized my modules was by playing with the route files.

You can add an auth checking (session) on the Base_controller that would redirect to the auth module, and there you would create a session based authentification system, the redirect to the main module.

The idea is that each module will be acting individually while still being integrated to the system by inheritance.

Edit :

I have checked your issues and read the code you provided and noticed 2 problems.

1- if you go through the source code of Form_Validation class at /system/libraries/Form_Validation.php, you will notice that the $CI field is protected and thus cannot be set like that, instead you could do this :

```
class My_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation()
{
     function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct(); // in the parent constructor : $this->CI =& get_instance(); 
     }
}
```

2- you are calling the ajaxFrom() by the id of the form, I think that you should override the normal submit behavior which normally sends a standard http request by an ajax call sending the form data and retrieving the response.

Comment: Thank you AchrafSoltani but I don't understand how to use your way and how does it solve my problem.
I do have 2 controllers Frontend and Admin. I also have a Base conroller: MY_Controller. I don't see how it solves the problem that the login view does not use the jQuery ajaxForm to submit the form?

Comment: I found it !!!
It was a mistake in the declaration of the form:
     echo form_open(site_url('auth/login', $attr);
Should be:
    echo form_open(site_url('auth/login'), $attr);